# Populated Selectbox option hide not working in IE & Safari

Tags: jquery, css

I have Populated selectbox. By default when page has loaded all options in the selectbox should be hide. I tried to hide it by Css, but output not working in IE & safari. Alternately i used jquery that too not working in IE & Safari.
Can you please help

### Css Way

```
select#CurriculumID option
{
    display: none;
}
```

### Jquery Way

```
jQuery('#CurriculumID option').css("display","none");
jQuery('#CurriculumID option').hide();
```

### My Html Looks Like

```
<select data-placeholder="PROGRAM OF INTEREST" data-placeholder-alternate="PROGRAM OF INTEREST" data-validate="required" id="CurriculumID" name="CurriculumID" title="Program"></select>
```

Selectbox option are populated from the backend

Comment: post some pieces of the html

Comment: Yes i used jQuery instead of $. Because its CMS (Drupal)

Comment: I change my anwser, show me some piece of the html

Comment: I want to know if this "option" is a class or other thing

Comment: I have Edited, Please look my addition "My Html Looks like"

Comment: so do you want hide all the select or just some info inside?

Comment: By default, All option in the selecobox should be hided. It has parent Select box. But the parent selectbox has hard coded. Based on the parent selectbox selection, populated select box showing corresponding option.

Comment: just disable the select $('#CurriculumID').attr('disabled','disabled')